# I have an error while I run throught cli interface: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, javafx

I have developed a javafx application with Intellij. The problem is that when I run the program through Intellij there aren't problem about it while if I run through command line or just double-clicking, the program doesn't run

Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Comment: Which JRE do you use? Find some [FAQs about the runtime environments here](https://java.com/en/download/faq/javafx.xml).

Comment: java version "12.0.2"

Comment: That doesn't contain JavaFX, have you installed it separately? If not, do so... Maybe even use OpenJFX.

Comment: I don't really know exactly what to configure because my last JavaFX experience was when the JDK and the JRE were including JavaFX. I think you have to set a PATH for it in your operating system. Or maybe use OpenJFX for compilation if that is possible in IntelliJ.

Comment: I have alredy installed OpenJFX. In fact, if I run the program through Intellij, it runs very well. The problem is if I double-click on it or if I run it throught the cli

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 11, JavaFX is not part of the JDK.  You have to add it yourself.

You also have to create a separate class to hold your `main` method.  It can be any class which doesn’t extend a JavaFX class.  This is because JavaFX loads native libraries, and the native library path isn’t available during the stage where Java is starting up the main class.

If your program is a module, you can just add the JavaFX SDK to your module path:

```
java -p /home/sette/projects/example/build:/opt/javafx-jmods-12 \
    -m com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.Startup
```

(If you’re running on Windows, replace `/` with `\`, and replace `:` with `;`.)

If your program is not a module, you need to include both the .jar files and the native libraries:

```
java -cp /home/sette/projects/example/build/MyApp.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-12/lib/"*" \
    -Djava.library.path=/opt/javafx-sdk-12/lib \
    com.example.myapp.Startup
```

Again, the main class (`Startup` in the above examples) must not extend javafx.application.Application.  It can and should call [Application.launch](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,java.lang.String...%29).